# Return number of lines from a string base on a character

Tags: php, substr

In PHP, how do I return the 6th or 5th or 4th lines from a string that looks like below.? A new line is define with the char `<br />`.

So, if i have a string like this

```
$lines = 4;
$lyrics = 'line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3<br />line 4<br /><br />line 5<br />line 6<br />line 7<br />line 8';
```

it should return

```
line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3<br />line 4
```

if i have

```
$lines = 4;
$lyrics = 'line 1<br />line 2';
```

it should return

```
line 1<br />line 2
```

Comment: New lines are defined by the character `'\n'` on some systems, which is not the same as the XHTML tag `<br />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into an array using [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php), use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the first *n* elements of the newly created array. Finally join them again.

```
$n = 4;
$lyrics = 'line 1<br />line 2<br />line 3<br />line 4<br /><br />line 5<br />line 6<br />line 7<br />line 8';
$lines = explode('<br />', $lyrics);
echo implode('<br />', array_slice($lines, 0, $n));
```